# Create new Fragment from a Fragment which is part of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I've seen many questions that seemed relevant, but I have failed to found the one that is exactly what I'm looking for.

I have an App, with a ViewPager in MainActivity.
one of the Fragments in the ViewPager is a ListFragment.
I want to enable a creation of new Fragment when the user clicks a List item,
using onListItemClick function.
The new Fragment will replace the ViewPager, and will display its layout and data.
I also want to allows clicking the Back button, which will return the User to the previous state of the PageViewer.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        StationDescriptionFragment newFragment = new StationDescriptionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(StationDescriptionFragment.ARG_DESCRIPTION, this.stationsList.get(position).getDescription());
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
```

This code is inside the Fragment which is part of the ViewPager.
This code ends and than the app crashes right after this function ends. I know for sure that this function ends.

The crash is:

```
FragmentManagerImpl.throwException(RuntimeException) line: 462
```

**The StationDescriptionFragment class:**

```
public class StationDescriptionFragment extends Fragment {
    final static String ARG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    String mCurrentDescription = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentDescription = savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_DESCRIPTION);
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_view, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        updateDescription("Some Description");
    }

    public void updateDescription(String description) {
        TextView desc = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.description);
        desc.setText(description);
        mCurrentDescription = description;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(ARG_DESCRIPTION, mCurrentDescription);
    }
}
```

**description_view.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: that crash is not helpful, can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The new Fragment will replace the ViewPager, and will display its
>   layout and data. I also want to allows clicking the Back button, which
>   will return the User to the previous state of the PageViewer.

If you want to replace the `ViewPager`(which I assume is in another fragment) along with its page fragments then use the normal `FragmentManager` and not the one returned by `getChildFragmentManager()` which is targeted at implementing nested fragments. `getChildFragmentManager()` will look for that id(to put the new fragment) in the current fragment's view and I assume `R.id.fragment_container` is the id of the container that holds the fragment with the `ViewPager`:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true); // call this before the transaction 
        StationDescriptionFragment newFragment = new StationDescriptionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(StationDescriptionFragment.ARG_DESCRIPTION, this.stationsList.get(position).getDescription());
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer - like you said, the issue was the getChildFragmentManager. I'm having an issue with the text not shown in the new Fragment. the desc.setText(description); doesn't seem not work. I will try and figure that out. Thanks again, you've really helped me.

Comment: @gioravered I'm glad I could help. One possible reason for that problem is searching for the `TextView` with `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.description);`(which is a cause for many subtle bugs). If you have somewhere else in your activity a `TextView` with that id you might end up updating that instead of the `TextView` from the fragment. If you want to change views from the fragment's view then always use `getView()`: `TextView desc = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.description);`. Might not be your case but try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have tried this, but still no text. the Fragment does replace itself, but the text is not shown. Also, it only replace the specific fragment and the view pager remains. I want to replace the whole View pager, with a regular fragment. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I've ended up with displaying the string in a Dialog - its better for the app, and it actually works! thank again!